# knn.fit(X_train, y_train) not showing parameters

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, knn

The output it shows, is below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vYjI.jpg)

I expected the output to be:

```
`KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski',
metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=1, p=2,
weights='uniform')`
```

As I am working through the book introduction to machine learning with Python by O'Reilly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `get_params` method on the fitted object.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

X = [[0], [1], [2], [3]]
y = [0, 0, 1, 1]

neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(algorithm='auto', leaf_size=30, metric='minkowski', metric_params=None, n_jobs=1, n_neighbors=1, p=2, weights='uniform')
neigh.fit(X, y)

neigh.get_params()
```

```
{'algorithm': 'auto',
 'leaf_size': 30,
 'metric': 'minkowski',
 'metric_params': None,
 'n_jobs': 1,
 'n_neighbors': 1,
 'p': 2,
 'weights': 'uniform'}
```